# How to remove all parentheses from a vector of string except when the parenthesis encompasses the entire string?

Tags: r, regex, string

I need to clean parentheses out of a vector of strings, but leave the parenthesis if it encompasses the entire value of the string. For example, I want to clean the following

```
strvec <- c("Apple(Inc)", "(*1)Apple(Inc)", "((*1)Samsung(Inc))", "Samsung", "(Ford Co.(London))")
```

so that I get the following vector of string :

```
c("Apple", "Apple", "(Samsung)", "Samsung", "(Ford Co.)")
```

The original data is a large vector (column inside a dataframe with > million rows) with a variety of values. Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Following @rawr's comment for more examples:

```
strvec2 <- c("((Ford Co.(London)) subsidiary)", "Apple(Inc(*1))")
```

should be cleaned as

```
c("( subsidiary)", "Apple")
```

Comment: `gsub('\\([^(]*?\\)', '', strvec)` ? do you have other test cases? can there be more nesting

Comment: There actually can be more nesting, up to 3.  (i.e. `"((Apple(Inc))'s subsidiary)"` Sorry for not making the example all-inclusive. If you post this as an answer I will mark it!

Comment: I added a couple more examples.. thank you for the comment!

Comment: The suggested pattern above only works to a certain extent. Have you checked the posted answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires a fairly complicated regex to meet all your requirements:

```
^\([^\(\)]+\)(?!$)|^\((?=.+\)$)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\((?:[^\(\)]|(?R))*\)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QhW9rH/2/)

Using it with `gsub`

```
gsub('^\\([^\\(\\)]+\\)(?!$)|^\\((?=.+\\)$)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\((?:[^\\(\\)]|(?R))*\\)', '', strvec, perl = TRUE)
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/h5Wh6H)

This contains a lot of nuts and bolts I guess you can further optimize it but it should do the trick.

Explanation

The first two major alternations deal with the special case `but leave the parenthesis if it encompasses the entire value of the string..`

- If there's a pair of parentheses that encloses the string from start to end we do not want to match: `^\((?=.+\)$)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`
- but match if there's a parenthesis at the beginning that is closed earlier:
  `^\([^\(\)]+\)(?!$)`

The remainder is a recursive pattern that captures the nested parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks!! My understanding is that this regex looks for two parts, (1) for `^\\([^\\(\\)]+\\)(?!$)` and (2) for the remainder. 

Then, in part (2), `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` apply only to `^\\((?=.+\\)$)`, and after excluding such case this regex looks for `\\((?:[^\\(\\)]|(?R))*\\)`. Is this correct? It's a bit confusing to me why `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` apply only to this part and not apply to parts covered in (1) as well.

Comment: You are welcome. I've added a bit more context. I hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate the context! Learned a lot from studying the regex (lookahead, etc.)